# Grails Maven project issue in execution mvn test

Tags: maven, grails, drools

I have issue in execution the `mvn -Dgrails.env=dev test`. 
All the unit tests passed but having issue in executing integration tests.

After doing lots of trial I narrow my problem to following

`grails test-app` working fine for all environment

`mvn -Dgrails.env=test test` is working fine

`mvn -Dgrails.env=dev test` throws exception related to following plugins 
either `DroolService` or `AuditLogEvent` or `PluginConfigGrailsPlugin` class not found though the class exists in target folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.2</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

If I comment drools plugins , then the test compile and works fine.

There is no issue in executing the application. Only issue in packaging using maven.

I had issue in running the `grails test-app` as well which is fixed by removing the commented line for `grails.project.fork.test` in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
//      compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

Maven commands working fine without any issue in test environment but having issue in any other environment.

Comment: Can you please remove the  <scope>compile</scope>  tag for drool and then try.

Comment: How would dropping the compile scope help? by default it's the compile scope which is applied by Maven anyway, so if you omit it, Maven will apply compile

Comment: Removing <scope>compile</scope> does not help.